# DateTime in Hyperledger

Tags: date, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I want to enter the participant's Date of Birth as input when i go to Test tab and click `+ Create New Participant` (JSON file).

But if I use the `DateTime` datatype as given in [github documentation for Hyperledger Composer Modeling Language](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/cto_language), the **current** date and time is auto inserted which I don't want. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

either you set it to a base epoch (yyyy-mm-dd) as a suggested format eg.

```
 o DateTime datefield default="1970-01-01" or
 o DateTime datefield default="1900-01-01"
```

or you just set it to nothing by using optional eg.

```
 o DateTime datefield optional
```

then (in data entry) you can supply the right `yyyy-mm-dd` (DoB) format only, as you wish in Playground 'Test' - it will set the remainder attributes for (T)ime as zeros and supply the right DateTime format.

cheers

Comment: Thanks, that worked! But gives me the unnecessary time also which isn't required in case of DoB. But that's Hyperledger's fault. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: What I was thinking is, I am going to integrate fabric with Front-end UI to make a web application. So, I can accept the DoB in date format which I can easily do in UI, and then convert it to String and then send it to fabric to store. Is it feasible??